# Loading Multiple R.Java with Library Project

Tags: android, r.java-file

I have 2 android projects in Eclipse, Application Project consuming the other exposed as Library Project (both having different package declaration in menifest.
Now Application Project has two IDENTICAL R.java files made from compiled resources ONLY from Application Project.
Where as Library Project is having only one R.java with compiled resources from itself.

When Application starts an Activity from Library, since the R.java refered in Application is the one within itself, when the flow is forwarded to Library Activity, no any member (e.g. Id) from view of Lobrary Acitivity is recognized. with noSuchFieldException.

I searched about class loader thing but no luck Is there any possibility to change the R.java we refer can be altered?

Thanks...

Comment: try after closing the project not currently working and restart eclipse

Comment: @RenjithKN I do not think that this is problem with workspace refresh, in Application project in Gen folder there are two packages with identical R.java file. And in Lobrary project there is one with different content. However at runtime always Previous one is picked and not the latest one.

Comment: Did u try to clean the project, delete the R files, it will re-generate new ones.

Comment: @Swarna Yes i did cleaned the projects and there is no any discrepency in Src Code and compiled code. However I just Start Activity from another one and the R.java loaded initialy is also propagated to next where I want the right R.java.

Comment: I've not tried library project, but I tried using another app as JAR file, and faced same problem. You cannot expose the R files of another project to be used in current project, have to remove those and create new sets in the current proj. I dont think it will refer to the exposed library.\